# Finding and debugging a memory leak without Valgrind

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management, valgrind

We have a program, that using IPC waits until it receives a message.
When the program receives a message, it process it, calls some stored procedures in a database and then returns an answer.

One of our clients noticed that every time we receive a message, the memory usage is increased in 20kb. This program is supposed to process more than a million messages a day, so I was tasked with fixing this leak.

The problem is that the program isn't a basic executable, but runs in a proprietary application server, and uses proprietary libraries for almost anything. Because of this, I can't run the program by itself, which makes it impossible to run programs like valgrind.

I created a simple function to read the current memory usage, and spammed it everywhere, but when I went to the code, it was just a function call.

Code to check memory usage.

```c
void PrintMemory(char *msg) {
    PREPARELOG(PrintMemory);
    FILE *fp = fopen("/proc/self/statm", "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        LOG(FAI, "[PrintMemory] Cant open /proc/self/statm");
        return;
    }
    long rss;

    fscanf(fp, "%*lu %ld", &rss);
    fclose(fp);

    LOG(NOT, "[PrintMemory] [%-30s] [%ld]", msg, rss);
}
```

Where `PREPARELOG`is a macro that sets some variables for the `LOG` macro.

After checking the log I see this:

```
[...]
[PrintMemory] [Function 1 end                ] [32633].
[PrintMemory] [Function 2 init               ] [32637].
[...]
```

Looking at the code, I see this:

```
ret = Function1(param);
PrintMemory("Function 1 end");

if (ret == 0) {
    Function2(&param1, &param2, param3, param4);
}
```

```
int Function2(int *param1, int *param2, char *param3, struct name* param4) {
    PREPARELOG(Function2);
    PrintMemory("Function 2 init");
    [...]
}
```

Checked the assembly of it just in case and saw this:

```
    call    PrintMemory #Function 1 end
    .loc 1 282 0
    movl    -28(%rbp), %eax # ret, ret.1
    testl   %eax, %eax  # ret.1
    jne .L37    #,
    .loc 1 283 0
    movq    -72(%rbp), %rcx # tx_switch, tmp80
    leaq    -64(%rbp), %rdx #, tmp81
    leaq    -28(%rbp), %rsi #, tmp82
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rax #, tmp83
    movq    %rax, %rdi  # tmp83,
    call    Function2 #
```

```
Function2:
.LFB9:
    .loc 1 965 0
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $64, %rsp   #,
    movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp) # param1, param1
    movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp) # param2, param2
    movq    %rdx, -40(%rbp) # param3, param3
    movq    %rcx, -48(%rbp) # param4, param4
    .loc 1 969 0
    movl    $.LC56, %edi    #,
    call    PrintMemory # Function 2 init
```

So my question is:
Is the output of PrintMemory correct?
Why would calling Function2 increase the memory by 3 pages (almost 12kB)?
Is there another way to find a memory leak, given that I can't run the program by itself?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I can't answer your question, but wanted to relate experience with a problem similar to this a while ago. Eventually solved it by replacing malloc, calloc, strdup, free, etc with macros that also logged the address being allocated/deallocated and the file name/line number to a file.  Then it was not hard to write a program that scanned the files matching up alloc/free pairs using the addresses.  The left over allocs gave the line numbers to look at.

Comment: @Gene I tried doing that using [mtrace(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mtrace.3.html) but the result wasn't too helpful, it threw out lot's of addresses, but most of them pointed to Oracle's libclntshcore, and couldn't find much of it online. Most of the code I'm using doesn't directly call malloc/callloc/etc either, so that's why I'm stumped.

Comment: Binary search the problem space.  `ltrace` and eBPF if you are on linux.

Comment: @AllanWind I can't launch the program by itself (It needs to be launched by the proprietary application server). Is there a way to attach ltrace to a running process?

Comment: Of course you _can_ run the program by itself. If proprietary_server launches the target_app, you can do `valgrind proprietary_server`. You have to be able to invoke the program or control the systemd script. Otherwise, you can't debug this. Having an external program monitor `/proc/self/statm` will tell you: "yes, the program is chewing memory" but _not_ which part of it. You'd need to watch the memory and have the watcher force the target to core dump so you can examine the stack and memory. So, if you can `kill` it, you can control it.

Comment: @ijzm `ltrace -p $pid`

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post [a lot] more information about the invocation, libraries used, etc. If you _can_ do (as Allan suggests) `lstrace -p $pid` this means you can also attach to it with `gdb` or a `ptrace` based program that you write/control. [As I've done before], you could write your own `malloc` wrappers that maintain a trace log of all allocations/frees (with the caller address). When it's clear the program has chewed memory, you can have the wrapper layer dump the trace (or just write it to a logfile as the program runs).

Comment: You can have the layer keep track of the total amount allocated, based on the caller address. So, you'll see that which callers just keep doing allocs without frees

Comment: Every time you call `fopen`, memory is allocated (about 16k, I think). When you call `fclose`, that memory is free'd, but there's no guarantee that the next `fopen` will just hand over the same memory. It depends on what memory allocations and deallocations have happened between the fclose and the fopen. So you should probably find a different way of logging memory usage.

Comment: "Because of this, I can't run the program by itself, which makes it impossible to run programs like valgrind." It's usually not impossible, unless you really can't change the string that is invoking the program. Valgrind just needs libc (and you can probably coerce it to run without that if needs be).

Comment: @PaulFloyd The main problem was, I wasn't able to invoke the program without crashing, as it needed to be called by the application server as a parent, and set all the environment variables/shared memory/more stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating I found [memleax](https://github.com/WuBingzheng/memleax) which did exactly what I needed.

Ran the program, attached memleax with `./memleax PID`, and triggered the leak. Then used memleak's output to find exactly what memory wasn't being freed.

As a sidenote: It looks like memleax is depreciated, but the alternative required running the program by itself, which is exactly what I wasn't able to do